# Spring @ControllerAdvice vs ErrorController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception, error-handling

In my REST service app, I am planning to create a `@ControllerAdvice` class to catch controller thrown exceptions and return `ResponseEntity` objects according to the error type.

But I already have a `@RestController` class implementing the `ErrorController` interface to catch all exceptions.

Do these two interfere in any manner?
In which cases will `ErrorController` be called when `@ControllerAdvice` exists?

Edit:
The `ErrorController` code as requested

```
@RestController
public class ControllerCustomError implements ErrorController{

    //error json object
    public class ErrorJson {

        public Integer status;
        public String error;
        public String message;
        public String timeStamp;
        public String trace;

        public ErrorJson(int status, Map<String, Object> errorAttributes) {
            this.status = status;
            this.error = (String) errorAttributes.get("error");
            this.message = (String) errorAttributes.get("message");
            this.timeStamp = errorAttributes.get("timestamp").toString();
            this.trace = (String) errorAttributes.get("trace");
        }

    }

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @Value("${hybus.error.stacktrace.include}")
    private boolean includeStackTrace = false;

    @Autowired
    private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    ErrorJson error(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // Appropriate HTTP response code (e.g. 404 or 500) is automatically set by Spring. 
        // Here we just define response body.
        return new ErrorJson(response.getStatus(), getErrorAttributes(request, includeStackTrace));
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, boolean includeStackTrace) {
        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
        return errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the code for your ErrorController

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question or is it still unsolved? Have you considered adding a bounty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An implementation of the `ErrorController` is used to provide a custom whitelabel error page.

A class annotated with `@ControllerAdvise` is used to add a global exception handling logic for the whole application. Thus, more than one controller in your application.

If in your application there is no mapping found for a request or page then spring will fallback to the 'whitelabel error page'. And in this case it will be the custom implementation of `ErrorController`

Comment: Not quite understand your explanation. Both `ErrorController` and `@ControllerAdvise` are used for more than one controller, what's the difference? And second question I'm looking for how to fall back to default white label error page for some conditions (spring profile, status code, etc).

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot, both `ErrorController` and `@ControllerAdvice` are used to handle and customize error responses, but they serve different purposes:

- `ErrorController` provides a way to customize error handling for specific error codes or situations and is typically used for handling standard HTTP errors.
- `@ControllerAdvice` is used for global exception handling across the application, allowing you to handle custom exceptions and providing consistent responses.

If you have both an implementation of `ErrorController` and a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` in your Spring Boot application, the `@ControllerAdvice` will be called first. The order of execution for exception handling in Spring Boot is as follows:

1. If an exception occurs within a controller method, Spring looks for a suitable `@ExceptionHandler` method within the same controller to handle that specific exception. If found, the `@ExceptionHandler` in the controller will be executed.
2. If no matching `@ExceptionHandler` is found within the controller, Spring will look for an appropriate `@ExceptionHandler` method in any class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`. If a matching `@ExceptionHandler` is found in the `@ControllerAdvice` class, it will be executed.
3. If no `@ExceptionHandler` is found in either the controller or the `@ControllerAdvice` class, Spring will fall back to its default error handling mechanism, which might involve invoking the `ErrorController` (if implemented) to handle the error.

Comment: Thanks Anar, good answer. If it's possible, please, add a best practice suggestion.

Comment: @Evmorov I don't think there is any best practice for this, since as my answer suggests, they have slightly different purposes. In general, `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` should be used in most cases, and `ErrorController` should only be implemented when you need to customize error handling for cases not covered by `@ExceptionHandler` methods.